# trimming \n \t from xmlChar not working

Tags: c++, boost

```
#include "boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp"
.
.
xmlChar *v = NULL;
cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
for (cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next) {
    v =  xmlGetProp(cur, (const xmlChar *)"value");
    trim((char*)v);
    printf("%s",v);
}
```

This code doesn't compile, says trim is not defined, I tried boost::trim and it did not help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boost::trim` is not working on C-strings. Use the temp `std::string` object and pass it to the `boost::trim`:

```
std::string tmp((char*)v);
boost::trim(tmp);
std::cout << tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at : [trim.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp).

Function defined in `::boost::algorithm` namespace. So use `::boost::algorithm::trim(...)`.

Comment: There's `using algorithm::trim;` at the bottom of `trim.hpp`.